# Create SQLAlchemy Model for pg_timezone_names (and add in relationship)

Tags: python, postgresql, join, sqlalchemy, internal

UPDATE:

It just works.

Even though you can't see the pg_* tables in reflection, you can build models on them.

So the answer is the question!

---

There's just too much going on here to connect the dots.

I have a Postgres database (schema? catalog?) with a set of tables. I have created models using `Base = declarative_base()`.

E.g:

```
class MyModel(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'mymodel'

    id = Column(UUIDType(binary=False), primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4)
    timezone = Column(Text)
    first_name = Column(Text)
```

There's this awesome table in pg_catalog: pg_timezone_names which I would like to join to the timezone column here.

`pg_timezone_names` is a view (not that is relevant necessarily) and in SQLA would look something like this (though I believe I SHOULD be able to build this automatically with `reflect`):

```
class TimezoneNames(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'pg_timezone_names'

    name = Column(Text, primary_key=True)
    abbrev  = Column(Text)
    utc_offset = Column(Interval)
    is_dst = Column(Boolean)
```

Let's say I connect with:

```
engine = create_engine("postgres://localhost:5432/mydb")
```

I would like to be able to grab a record from MyModel and access the `utc_offset` by creating a relationship with the pg_timezone_names table.

When I try to grab `Base.classes`, I only see `mymodel` but not any of the `pg_catalog` tables.  Yet when I'm in `mydb` I can perform:

```
SELECT * from pg_timezone_names WHERE name LIKE "%America%";
```

In other words, it's totally easy in `psql` to perform the query.  But how do I specify the model connects to that table?

I believe I could change my model to:

```
class MyModel(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'mymodel'

    id = Column(UUIDType(binary=False), primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4)
    timezone_name = Column(Text ForeignKey('pg_timezone_names.name'))
    first_name = Column(Text)
    timezone = relationship("TimezoneNames")
```

So that I can grab the record's utc_offset with something like this:

```
myOffset = session.query(MyModel).first().timezone.utc_offset
```

The question is:

**How do I tell sqlalchemy to find `pg_timezone_names` so I can create the relationships I want?**

Thanks for your consideration!

Comment: have you tried `session.query(MyModel).join(TimezoneNames)...`?

Comment: @AzatIbrakov My problem is making the connection to the `pg_timezone_names` table.  I am not sure if sqlalchemy actually finds the table.  Am I just being obtuse here?  Does my code above already answer my question?

Comment: what output do you have? any errors?

Comment: Holy crap.  It just worked....  :-)  I needed to make the name column a primary key, but it did it.  The additional question is whether I could have done this with reflection, but I don't think so since the view doesn't seem to have a primary key...   I'll update the code above.